# MKViewAnnotation custom annotations losing order when added in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parsing, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I need to show on my MkMapView about 10 locations and respective custom annotations images (depending from the values loaded by a **JSON parsing**). As suggested in [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707080/after-json-parsing-viewforannotation-shows-only-one-single-annotation-on-mkmapv#comment20582455_14714453) I have created a custom annotation class to store some data but, again, I cannot get the RIGHT ORDER: the custom images on each map locations don't respect the right sequence of respective parsed values, while in a UITableView its all perfect. This is the simplified code:

**The example of correspondence:**

```
if parsed valuesID is 100 ---> annotation image must be 100.png
if parsed valuesID is 200 ---> annotation image must be 200.png
if parsed valuesID is 300 ---> annotation image must be 300.png
```

**The viewDidLoad method:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    map.showsUserLocation = true;
    map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

    #define MakeLocation(lat,lon) [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:lon]

    locations= @[ MakeLocation(lat1,lon1), MakeLocation(lat2,lon2), MakeLocation(lat3,lon3), MakeLocation(lat4,lon4), MakeLocation(lat5,lon5), MakeLocation(lat6,lon6), MakeLocation(lat7,lon7), MakeLocation(lat8,lon8), MakeLocation(lat9,lon9), MakeLocation(lat10,lon10) ];
}
```

**The parseMethod called by a UIButton:**

```
   - (IBAction)parseMethod {

        [map removeAnnotations:map.annotations];

        // THE COMPLEX CODE TO PARSE VALUES of valuesID
        ...
        ... // so here I have the full array of valuesID
        ...
        // THE CONTROL FOR THE END OF COMPLETE PARSING (blocks, cycle, ... )

        [self addAnnotations]; // here i'm sure to call method AFTER THE END of complete parsing

    }
```

**The MyAnnotation2.h custom class:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotation2 : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int valuesIDMyAnnotation2;

@end
```

**The MyAnnotation2.m custom class:**

```
#import "MyAnnotation2.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation2

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize valuesIDMyAnnotation2;

@end
```

**The addAnnotations method (called AFTER the COMPLETE END of parsing):**

```
- (void)addAnnotations {

    [table reloadData]; // UITableView with rows populated with locations coordinates and respective valuesID
    [table scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];

    for (int l=0; l<[locations count]; l++) {

        annotation2 = [[MyAnnotation2 alloc] init]; // create MyAnnotation2 istance to assign custom properties
        annotation2.valuesIDMyAnnotation2 = [[valuesID objectAtIndex:l] intValue];
        annotation2.coordinate = [locations[l] coordinate];
        [map addAnnotation: annotation2]; // here we call delegate with all necessary data to add annotations, both location coordinate and corresponding valuesID

        NSLog(@"%d - COORDINATES: %f - %f",annotation2.valuesIDMyAnnotation2,annotation2.coordinate.latitude, annotation2.coordinate.longitude);
    }

}
```

**The UITableView delegate**:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:
                UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[coordinates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // here coordinates are values from each location

            if ([[valuesID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 100) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"100.png"];
                [cell.imageView setImage:image];
            }
            if ([[valuesID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 200) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"200.png"];
                [cell.imageView setImage:image];
            }
            if ([[valuesID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] == 300) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"300.png"];
                [cell.imageView setImage:image];
            }
    return cell
}
```

**Finally, the viewForAnnotation delegate:**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {

    if ( ! [annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation2 class]])
    {
        ((MKUserLocation *)annotation).title = @"My position";
    return nil;
    }

    MKAnnotationView *pinView= [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];

    MyAnnotation2 *myPin = (MyAnnotation2 *)annotation;

    if (myPin.valuesIDMyAnnotation2 == 100) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"100.png"];
    }
    if (myPin.valuesIDMyAnnotation2 == 200) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"200.png"];
    }
    if (myPin.valuesIDMyAnnotation2 == 300) {
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"300.png"];
    }
    [pinView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
    return pinView;

}
```

**EDIT - example of NSLogs results (code from addAnnotations method):**

```
100 - COORDINATES lat1 - lon1 // here I expect annotation images100.png on location1
200 - COORDINATES lat2 - lon2 // ...
100 - COORDINATES lat3 - lon3
300 - COORDINATES lat4 - lon4
100 - COORDINATES lat5 - lon5
200 - COORDINATES lat6 - lon6
100 - COORDINATES lat7 - lon7
300 - COORDINATES lat8 - lon8
300 - COORDINATES lat9 - lon1
200 - COORDINATES lat10 - lon10
```

**RESULTS:**
On the UITableView its all PERFECT, I can see the right correspondence between locations coordinates and custom images, and also NSLog() gives the right correspondence of both location and valuesID. On the MKMapView, instead, custom annotation images **are not added in the right sequence** so I have right annotations images but in the wrong locations. Please, help me again to resolve this issue, thanks!

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, the same image is being assigned for all three ifs.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes @AnnaKarenina, it has been my transcription error: now I've corrected it and added also the UITableView delegate, to provide more precise and clear code. Thanks!

Comment: Another typo: `annotation2.valueIDMyAnnotation2 = ` should be `annotation2.valuesIDMyAnnotation2 = ` (missing `s` before `ID`) -- it's much better if you copy+paste the exact code instead of re-typing.  Anyway, there is no obvious issue in the code posted.  Only possibility is that the `coordinates` array (which the table view is using) does not match up with the `locations` array (which the annotations are using).

Comment: Oh, but this is absolutely incredible. Do u see the for () loop in -addAnnotations method? In NSLog results I can read, for example: "100 - COORDINATES lat1 - lon1", but on MKMapView, the location with lat1 and lon1 coordinates has annotation image200.png... I'm losing my head!

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point on each of the `pinView.image` lines and when it is setting the image200.png, check what the coordinates are (you might need to NSLog them, I've never been great at digging deep in the debugger data). If you've got a mismatch there look through the rest of your code of anything else that could be changing the values of the locations, anything at all, and put a break point there. If that breakpoint gets triggered between the `parseMethod` and `viewForAnnotation` then you might have your culprit.

Comment: Thank you @Craig, I have tried to add break points but, again, there is no way to understand: BEFORE the `[map addAnnotation:annotation2]` I have all the data sorted and in the right order, as u can see in the NSLog results, so I cannot get the issue.

Comment: What were the results from the break points? What where the coordinates when the image was being set, correct or incorrect?

Comment: Well, @AnnaKarenina was right: after days of code debugging I have noticed that ONLY FOR SOME LOCATIONS the `coordinates` array did not match up with the right `locations`... issue resolved.

Comment: Would you care to explain how the two arrays did not match up?

Comment: Simple, it was my error: I had declared some `MakeLocation(lat,lon)` with wrong latitude and longitude values, so the CORRESPONDING parsing values didn't match with the right location on the map (in the parseMethod, to parse valuesID, I don't use lat,lon but a corresponding GeoNamesID array).